# Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

Tags: differential-equations

I am exploring the Swinging Atwood Machine in my theoretical mechanics course. I have derived the following motions of equations and am trying to solve the ODEs with the specified parameters. My goal is to get the functions and then plot the phase space using parametric plotting.

```
Soln = NDSolve[{r'[t] == pr[t]/(M + m), s'[t] == ps[t]/(m r[t]^2),
         pr'[t] == ((ps[t])^2)/(m r[t]^3) - M g + m g cos (s[t]), 
         ps'[t] == - m g r[t] (sin (s[t])), 
         r[0] == 5, pr[0] == 0, ps[0] == 0, s[0] == 0.613}, 
         {r[t], s[t], pr[t], ps[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

But before I get that far I am getting this error:

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please note the indentations in the NDSolve are only for formatting purposes on here so that it is easier to read.

Comment: All parameters given to `NDSolve` must have numerical values; it does not work with symbolic parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the syntax of `sin` and `cos`, the correct ones are `Sin[]` and `Cos[]`,

```
M = 1; m = 1; g = 1;

Soln = NDSolve[{r'[t] == pr[t]/(M + m), s'[t] == ps[t]/(m r[t]^2), 
   pr'[t] == ((ps[t])^2)/(m r[t]^3) - M g + m g Cos[s[t]], 
   ps'[t] == -m g r[t] (Sin [s[t]]), r[0] == 5, pr[0] == 0, 
   ps[0] == 0, s[0] == 0.613}, {r[t], s[t], pr[t], ps[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate[{r[t], s[t], pr[t], ps[t]} /. Soln], {t, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it!